# Как сделать Android приложение с каталогом продуктов?

Tags: java, android

Нужно сделать приложение под Android с каталогом продуктов, и их описание. В каталоге примерно 100 продуктов. И для каждого нужно своё описание.

Создавать для каждого разметку (xml) и Activity - я думаю не лучший вариант.

Comment: Активити (и соответственно разметок) понадобится только две - список и детальный вид. Получив какой-либо идентификатор при клике в списке вы передаете его во второе активити, где по этому идентификатору извлекаются данные (например из БД). Полученные данные отображаются затем во второй активити. В Android Studio есть готовый шаблон Master Detail Flow, который реализует базовую логику такого кейса.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2 активити: список продуктов и детали продукта.
По нажатию на элемент списка во вторую активити через intent летит сериализованный объект продукта или id, или еще что-то, смотря где вы хранить будете все это.

Answer (score 2):

Могу посоветовать книгу, в которой очень детально описана эта ситуация и как сделать подобное приложение. Книга называется: "Android Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide". Есть уже второе издание на русском языке. Найди там пример создания приложения Criminal Intent (самое большое в книге) и там будут все ответы на твои вопросы. Кроме этого там есть еще очень много полезного.